Doxygen ignores NO_DIAGRAM
I'm documenting a C++ project with Doxygen and I want the dependency graph to only include my header file, not other libraries. I have it like this:
#ifndef CJT_ROBOT_HH
#define CJT_ROBOT_HH
#include "Machine.hh"
#include "BinTree.hh"
#ifndef NO_DIAGRAM
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <set>
#endif

If I select in the Doxygen GUI to use the built-in class generator, no graph is generated. If I use the dot tool from GraphViz, the NO_DIAGRAM is ignored.

You are missing the second #endif, which corresponds to the outer #ifndef.

Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you be a bit more specific / give a complete example (miight be easier to do this in the discussion part on GitHub: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/discussions)
